# 【Gradle sync failed: Connection refusedと表示されrunできない】Android Studio：GitHubからのダウンロード、

Tags: java, android-studio, github

GitHubからコードをダウンロードし、Android Studioのエミュレータで動かしたいです。しかし、Gradleの同期がGradle sync failed: Connection refused: と表示されてしまいます。GitHubでダウンロードしたソースコードがEclipseで作成したものだからでしょうか？調べてみましたが、上手くいきません。ご教示願います。

**イベントログ**

```
 8:07   Gradle 同期が開始されました
 
 8:07   Gradle sync failed: Connection refused: connect         
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (16 s 189 ms)
```

**ビルド：同期化**

```
Connection refused: connect
```

**gradle-Wrapper.properties**

```
#Sun Oct 11 16:54:08 JST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

**build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**プロジェクト構造**

```
・プロジェクト構造＞ビルド・ツール・バージョン＞30.02

・プロジェクト構造＞プロジェクト＞Andorid Gradle プラグインバージョン＞4.0.2

・プロジェクト構造＞プロジェクト＞Gradle プラグインバージョン＞5.6.4
```

**行ったこと**

・ファイル＞キャッシュの削除、再起動を行った。

・プロジェクト構造＞モジュール＞app＞プロパティ＞SDKのバージョンをコンパイルする＞22を29に変えた。

・gradle-Wrapper.propertiesのdistributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zipのgradle-5.6.4-が最新らしいので、元の数字から変更した。

Comment: プロキシー・サーバー経由でインターネットに接続している環境ではないですか？

Comment: そうかもしれません。ただ、一度Android Studioをアンインストールし、インストールしなおしたところ、Android Studioが起動すらしなくなりました。一度、パソコンを初期化しようかと思います。

Comment: Android Studio4.1が起動しない問題が解決しましたので、プロキシサーバー調べてみます。https://qiita.com/mohhu/items/ab81a5160b80383132e2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradleスクリプト＞build.gradleの

```
    dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2を4.0.1に変更したら、解決した。

ちなみに、別のプロジェクトを開いた時も、また接続エラーになったので、おっしゃるようにHttpプロキシを変更した。こちらを参考にしたら解決した。感謝します。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63157065/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle4-0-1-or-4-0-0